# Ubercart Line item tax not displayed first time

Tags: ubercart, commerce

Im adding a line item to ubercart order at checkout validation. When at the review page I can see the line item but its not used in the tax calculation. But when i go to the review page for the second time it is.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I added the line items at validate. However at that moment the tax is already calculated. What needs to happen is recalc the taxes. This can be done from a ajax call when a field changes value.

```
function My_Module_update_line_items($form, $form_state) {
  $commands = array();
  if (isset($form['panes']['payment']['line_items'])) {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#line-items-div', drupal_render($form['panes']['payment']['line_items']));
    $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('#line-items-div', theme('status_messages'));
  }

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```